# Running phpMyAdmin and php-7 at the same time?

Tags: php, debian, phpmyadmin, php7

After upgrading **php5** to **php7**, I get this error when I want to `apt-get install phpmyadmin`

```
The following packages have unmet dependencies:
 phpmyadmin : Depends: libapache2-mod-php5 but it is not going to be installed or
                       libapache2-mod-php5filter but it is not going to be installed or
                       php5-cgi but it is not going to be installed or
                       php5-fpm but it is not going to be installed or
                       php5 but it is not going to be installed
              Depends: php5-mysql but it is not going to be installed or
                       php5-mysqli but it is not installable or
                       php5-mysqlnd but it is not going to be installed
              Depends: php5-mcrypt but it is not going to be installed
              Depends: php5-json but it is not going to be installed
              Depends: php-gettext but it is not going to be installed
              Recommends: php5-gd but it is not going to be installed
E: Unable to correct problems, you have held broken packages.
```

It's indicating that phpMyAdmin requires php5, but the dependencies can't be installed because php7 is already installed.

**Is there a way to install phpMyAdmin and php7 at the same time?**

I'm using these additional sources

> deb http://packages.dotdeb.org jessie all
>   deb-src http://packages.dotdeb.org jessie all

Using Debian Jessie.

Comment: do you found any solution? I'm running into the same problem. I'm considering to switch to ubuntu for this server, but I would rather solve the problem

Comment: Like in the answer below explained: This would be just fiddling with different versions / building phpMyAdmin yourself, etc. I will wait until php7 becomes widely available.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Using php7 and any OS packages will be difficult until distros (or third party repos) are updated to handle this and you really shouldn't do this on a production system.

My advice is to not attempt this and wait until a PHP7 infrastructure is in place. You could work around by installing most things like PHPMyAdmin by hand, but this is not good system management practice.

Comment: Any idea when php-7 will be widely available via apt-get?

Answer (score 1):

I was able to get this to work on my VPN by running this command in my web root folder (/var/www/html).

```
git clone --depth=1 --branch=STABLE https://github.com/phpmyadmin/phpmyadmin.git
```

This probably isn't best practice, but will work.

Comment: fixed all the issues I was having on mac (MAMP) and linux for me

Comment: might be worth adding that you also need to run "composer install" in the phpmyadmin directory after pulling